# Pagination in one to many relationship with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, pagination, one-to-many

I Want to display 6 records from a database table.
 There is one-to many relationships between 2 tables. With custom mapper, I mapped these records as follows.

```
$result  = [
   0=>[
        "name"=>"jithin",
        "phone"=>"907856",
        "messages"=>[
                      0=>[
                          "title"=>"text messgae"
                         ],
                      1=>[
                          "title"=>"Data messgae"
                         ]
                    ]
      ],
    1=>[
        "name"=>"Rijin",
        "phone"=>"90247856",
        "messages"=>[
                      0=>[
                          "title"=>"text messgae"
                         ],
                      1=>[
                          "title"=>"Data messgae"
                         ]
                    ]
      ]
]
```

QUERY

```
"SELECT u.* , m.* FROM user u INNER JOIN messages m ON m.userId = u.id
 WHERE m.date BETWEEN "12-12-2015" AND "12-12-2018" LIMIT 0, 6;
```

This query will return data like

```
userId | name | messages|
-------|------|---------|
1      |jithin| hai     |
1      |jithin| hello   |
1      |jithin| Why?    |
2      |Rijin | hai     |
2      |Rijin | Where   |
2      |Rijin | Why?    |
-------------------------
```

But I need another 4 more records of another 4 persons.
I'm using php and mysql5.7.

Comment: Can you show what is in your dataset and what result do you want ?

Comment: I need 6 person records.
Two tables
user and messages.
user table contains userId, userName, phoneNumber fields,
and messages table contain userId(foreign key), messageId, message

Comment: This query returns 6 records but which contain one to many relationship. Therefore I can't manage pagination.

Comment: I need 6 person records.
Two tables
user and messages.
`user` table contains `userId, userName, phoneNumber fields,`
and `messages` table contain `userId(foreign key), messageId, message`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your needs :

```
    SELECT u.id, u.userName , m.message
    FROM user u 
    INNER JOIN messages m ON m.userId = u.id
    INNER JOIN (SELECT u.id as user_id FROM user u LIMIT 0, 6) as users
        ON users.user_id = u.id
    WHERE m.date BETWEEN '12-12-2015' AND '12-12-2018';
```

Comment: Yes. I wrote this answer already. Thanks for your support. If you can find another solution for this problem please post here

Answer (score 0):

At last, I found the answer to this question.

```
"SELECT u.* , m.* FROM user u 
 INNER JOIN messages m ON m.userId = u.id
 INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT u.id as user_id FROM user u 
             INNER JOIN messages m ON m.userId = u.id
             WHERE m.date BETWEEN "12-12-2015" 
             AND "12-12-2018" LIMIT 0, 6) 
 AS distinct_users ON distinct_users.user_id=u.id
 WHERE m.date BETWEEN "12-12-2015" AND "12-12-2018";
```

this will return exact 6 persons messages and we can easily manage pagination.
If you have another simple option. please post here.